# Product of maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $I$ and $J$ be two maximal ideals in a PID $R$ and $R$ is not a field. Then how will I show that $IJ$ is never a prime ideal?

Please provide me a hint. Thanks.

Comment: Think of unique factorisation. $I$ and $J$ are generated by irreducible elements.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $I$ and $J$ are comaximal for $I \neq J$, so by the Chinese Remainder Theorem
$$ \frac{R}{IJ} \cong \frac{R}{I} \times \frac{R}{J} $$
which is not an integral domain. Indeed, $(\overline1,0)$ and $(0,\overline1)$ are in $\frac{R}{I} \times \frac{R}{J} $  and their product is zero. Hence, $IJ$ is not prime.

If $I = J$ and the statement doesn't hold, we must have that $I^2$ is a prime ideal. But $R$ is a PID so we must have that $I^2$ is maximal. Now, $$ I^2\subseteq I \subseteq R .$$
Thus we must have $I=I^2\ne\{0\}$ (because $R$ is not a field). If $I=\langle a\rangle$ then $I^2=\langle a^2\rangle$ (try to prove it). In particular $$\langle a\rangle=\langle a^2\rangle.$$ Then $a=a^2x$ for some $x \in R$, which implies $a$ is a unit. This is a contradiction to $I$ being maximal.

Comment: What if $I=J$ ?

Comment: I had exactly this thought  in my mind but I discard it thinking it will be easy. But, this is not (maybe there is some other way, I have to look). If $I=J$ by maximality we must have $I^2=I$, And one can use NAK lemma to show that $I$ is generetaed by an idempotent,e . But the only idempotents in an ID are $o,1$. $e=1$ is a contradiction to I is maximal. If $e=0$ the proof is trivial.

Comment: $I^2=I$ isn't true. Take $R=\mathbb Z$, and $I=(p)$ for some prime $p$.

Comment: No, I mean if I=J and if the statement doesn't hold. We must have $I^2$ is prime ideal. But R is a pid so we must have $I^2$ is maximal. Now, $$  I^2 \subset I $$. Thus, $I=I^2$.

Comment: OK. It's a fine solution, but CRT + Naka is not as easy as the problem itself.

Comment: Exactly. I had ignored the case of equality. Might find some easier way to solve this case later.

Answer (score 1):

As $I$ and $J$ are maximals, we have that both are generated by irreducible elements, then let's write $I=(u)$ and $J=(v)$, for some irreducibles $u,v$. Then $IJ=(uv)$. Now, since both $u$ and $v$ are irreducibles, it's easy to see that $uv$ is not an irreducible element, let alone a prime element of $R$. Hence, $IJ$ is not a prime ideal.